# multiple selector with jquery autocompelte plugin with rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I have used the jquery auto complete plugin in my rails application and things are working fine.

I want to enter multiple names separated by commas and would require auto complete for each that are separated by commas. Please help me with the required option for this.

My jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $.getJSON('/releases/new.json', function(data1) {      
        $('#release_tester_tokens').autocomplete({source: names}, {multipleSeparator:  ","});  
    });  
});
```

Comment: will u please provide the link of plugin ( autocomplete ) you are using,

Comment: @diEcho .Please find the link here .http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Comment: @ramya: seen this anywhere? "This plugin is deprecated and not developed anymore... This page will remain as it is for reference, but won’t be updated anymore."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either you need to write some methods with yourself.
here is one **[helpful article](http://www.techistuffs.com/2011/12/jquery-tweaking-auto-complete-plugin.html)**

or you can use another *plugin*

### update

if there is an option then you can try with this way

```
$("#tagnames").autocomplete("/tags/filter", {
        max: 6,
        highlightItem: true,
        multiple: true,
        multipleSeparator: ",", 
  })
```

`NOTE`: Read the **comments** on [plugin website](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)

#### http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: Hi diEcho Thanka a lot for answering. We have an option called multiSelector in the plugin already. Could you please help with how it works?

Comment: @ramya i have updated the code.
 tip : you must read documentation for that. that will help u better. ALL D BEST

Comment: Hi DiEcho .Thanks a lot for helping me with all the possible solutions . The problem I am facing is I am able to get the auto compelte if I use source:names as the option.But with this I am not able to get the effect of multiple:true. This is my guess